# Simulate universal gravitation for two Sprite Kit nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two nodes in Sprite Kit, and I'm writing in Swift.

How would I make the nodes attracted to each other by the force of gravity? Also, how would I use their masses? If an object has a big mass, it should gravitate more.

Comment: You should update your question to show some effort in solving this problem so far as well as to add an additional data like : what version of Xcode you are using, what iOS you have installed on device... That way, you will probably get an useful answer. StackOverflow is not a site where people write whole solutions for you, but rather a site with people eager to help when you are stuck.

Comment: To be honest it's not a bad question in principle and could be useful for future readers. It was not worded that great and shows no effort at attempting the solution which is where the question fails, but to be fair the calculations needed to simulate this can be challenging for those who are unfamiliar with simulating rigid body physics.

Comment: I agree with Epic Byte. This was actually really useful for me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can loop through all nodes and calculate the impulse to all other nodes using the appropriate ratios of the universal gravitation equation. I just wrote a quick example showing how this is done. You can make your own custom "mass" factor, however I'm simply using Sprite Kit's. I also added a strength factor to amplify the impulse. I'm also assuming fixed time step of 1/60 seconds.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var nodes: [SKShapeNode] = []
    let dt: CGFloat = 1.0/60.0 //Delta time.
    let radiusLowerBound: CGFloat = 1.0 //Minimum radius between nodes check.
    let strength: CGFloat = 10000 //Make gravity less weak and more fun!
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector()
        for i in 1 ... 50 { //Create 50 random nodes.
            let rndRadius = 15 + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(20))
            let rndPosition = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.width))), y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height))))
            let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: rndRadius)
            node.position = rndPosition
            node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: rndRadius)
            self.addChild(node)
            nodes.append(node)
        }
    }
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        for node1 in nodes {
            for node2 in nodes {
                let m1 = node1.physicsBody!.mass*strength
                let m2 = node2.physicsBody!.mass*strength
                let disp = CGVector(dx: node2.position.x-node1.position.x, dy: node2.position.y-node1.position.y)
                let radius = sqrt(disp.dx*disp.dx+disp.dy*disp.dy)
                if radius < radiusLowerBound { //Radius lower-bound.
                    continue
                }
                let force = (m1*m2)/(radius*radius);
                let normal = CGVector(dx: disp.dx/radius, dy: disp.dy/radius)
                let impulse = CGVector(dx: normal.dx*force*dt, dy: normal.dy*force*dt)

                node1.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: node1.physicsBody!.velocity.dx + impulse.dx, dy: node1.physicsBody!.velocity.dy + impulse.dy)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Instead of performing the calculation manually you could also add [field nodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) to your physics bodies to simulate the effect. Although be warned, field nodes are [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26892892/2158465) in certain versions of Sprite Kit.

Comment: Correct link to [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode)