# How to calculate final force vector for the SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skfieldnode

Good afternoon, everybody!

I am creating space game which has an effect similar to black hole's gravitational effect. Wherever the spaceship is going, the black hole will attract it, summing up all the vectors together.

I know [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/noiseFieldWithSmoothness:animationSpeed:) has a method [customFieldWithEvaluationBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/customFieldWithEvaluationBlock:) that allows to calculate everything myself, but might it be another way to do that?

I have tried almost every type in [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/noiseFieldWithSmoothness:animationSpeed:), but nothing helped.

1. There are some side effects that don't suit me (i.e. If I use an electric or magnetic field, the object repels from the black hole)
2. Moreover, moving with [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/) (i.e. for the spaceship) doesn't allow me to sum all movement vectors together (I cant do
   `- (void)moveTo:duration:` actions simultaneously, even with grouping the actions)

What can you advice me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [radial gravity field](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/radialGravityField)? :)

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500104/simulate-universal-gravitation-for-two-sprite-kit-nodes

Comment: @0x141E yeah, but there are specific calculations that need to be done (but its helpful anyway, thanks a lot)