# SpriteKit/SKPhysics radialGravityField of same category always attracting each others?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skfieldnode

Running into an issue trying to use the radial gravity fields in SpriteKit

I don't want objects of same kind (as define by categoryBitMask to attract each others)

Here's how I do it :

```
struct PhyscisCategory {
    static let None : UInt32 = 0
    static let All : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Star : UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Planet : UInt32 = 0b10
}
<....>
 Planet1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhyscisCategory.Planet
 Planet1.physicsBody!.fieldBitMask = PhyscisCategory.Star

 Planet2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhyscisCategory.Planet
 Planet2.physicsBody!.fieldBitMask = PhyscisCategory.Star
```

Whatever I tried Planets are always mutually attracted (except if I set the fieldBitMask to 0, but they are of course not anymore attracted by Star either) ! I would expect of this 2 lines of code that only stars gravity fields would behave an effect on planets...

from the documentation :

**"fieldBitMask :
A mask that defines which categories of physics fields can exert forces on this physics body.
When a physics body is inside the region of an SKFieldNode object, that field node’s categoryBitMask property is compared to this physics body’s fieldBitMask property by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero value, the field node’s effect is applied to the physics body."**

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Well problem seems deeper :  I made some additional tests and the fieldBitMask seems totally ignored except when it is set to 0 or all 1.... (I'm targeting ios 9 App in xcode 7)

Comment: May want to use this as a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31502698/2158465

Comment: Thanks for the advise... Working fine reimplementing the gravity field and the categoryBitMask&fieldBitMask check...

Answer (score 1):

Your masks are out of whack. In binary, they look like this:

```
0000 0000 1011 0001 (stars)
0000 1011 0001 0000 (planets)
```

A logical `AND` of those two yields a non-zero value :

```
0000 0000 0001 0000
```

So if `SpriteKit` evaluates your planet's field bitmask with another planet's category bitmask, they will attract each other. Try those masks instead:

```
static let Star : uint32_t = 0x1 << 0
static let Planet : uint32_t = 0x1 << 1
```

(Not sure if that is valid swift code, but you get the idea). You can extend the masks by always left-shifting one bit further. These masks will then always yield a zero value if being `AND`-ed.

Comment: nope they're ok... :)
0b1   = ..0000001
0b10 = ..0000010

Comment: But each hex digit converts to four binary digits. 1 = 0001, b = 1011. Have you tried the shifting method? I think one of us gets something wrong.

Comment: it's not hex notation (0x...) but swift binary notation (0b....) they are UINT32 (32 bits)  0b1 = 1 0b10 = 2 0b100 = 4

Comment: Ohhh I see. My bad, then :) I should really start learning Swift.