# Constantly change the direction of gravity to be where an object is randomly moving

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, gravity

I have an object that is randomly moving, and other objects are spawning next to it.

How can I change the gravity direction of the objects that are being spawned to make it so the spawned objects are always moving towards my randomly moving object?

In my `didMoveToView` I tried adding the following:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(costantlyMovingObject.position.x, constantlyMovingObject.position.y)
```

But this just causes the spawned objects to fly around like crazy

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500104/simulate-universal-gravitation-for-two-sprite-kit-nodes

Comment: Yep, turns out your suggestion is what I actually was looking for @0x141E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move all objects toward your object, you should use a SKFieldNode [`radialGravityField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/radialGravityField).