# SpriteKit: Node moves away when placed in the centre of spring field

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Say we have scene with spring field node at the (0;0) and some node affected by this field.

Weird thing: if we put node at (0;0), it flies away immediately with huge speed; if put at some offset, like (0;10), it moves toward field node, oscillates for some time before stay at (0;0) and then flies away. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What do you expect the spring field to do?

Comment: Pull node to the centre and keep it there

Comment: I just implemented what you described and the node moves toward the spring field, oscillates for a while, and stops at the field's center. If I place the node at the center of the spring field, it just stays there. What field node parameters are you using?

Comment: Default ones as set in SceneBuilder: strength 1, falloff -1, animation speed 0, min radius 0,00457763671875

Comment: I updated my code to use the scene builder and the same results are the same. What parameters are you using for the physics body?

Comment: Seems found a key. All time I run app on iOS 8 simulator. When I tried simulator with iOS 10 and device with iOS 9 - bug disappeared. But still no idea what the problem.

Comment: SpriteKit's magnetic and electric fields did not work as expected in iOS 8 as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583736/skfieldnode-magneticnode-attracting-forces). Perhaps the spring field had a similar bug that was fixed in a later version.

Comment: Right, I noticed that too using electric field.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this only appears in iOS 8.

Problem lurks in calculation of force multiplier. If we set falloff = 0 or min radius = 0, such behaviour doesn't appear. So setting minRadius to 0 solved the problem. Thanks @0x141E for support.

Upd:

I was wrong - setting minRadius doesn't solve the problem. I didn't noticed that field coordinates displayed as (0;0) in Scene Editor in a fact were non-zero, delta was about 1*10^-4, while node was placed exactly at (0;0). Such quite small initial distance seems to help, but can't say what will happen if node eventually stay at the centre of the field.

For this time solution is to add initial distance and wait for end of iOS 8 support for app.